# Afree chart : How to increase X axis values(gap or domain range) while zooming

Tags: android, jfreechart

Can anyone help me on below zooming!
While doing horizontal zoom, I would like to increase and display the gap or range.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/184003479/actual.png]

Now the range is on attached link is 10,12,14,16... while zooming it should display as 10,11,12,13,...
How I can increase this domain range while zooming. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protected static int gapValue; //gap between two dates

private void zoom(PointF source, double startDistance, double endDistance) {

```
    Plot plot = this.chart.getPlot();
    PlotRenderingInfo info = this.info.getPlotInfo();

    if (plot instanceof Zoomable) {
        float scaleDistance = (float) (startDistance / endDistance);
    //for maintaining the limit of zooming range  horizontally
        if (this.mScale * scaleDistance <= 1.0f
                && this.mScale * scaleDistance > 0.1f) {
            this.mScale *= scaleDistance;
            Zoomable z = (Zoomable) plot;
            z.zoomDomainAxes(scaleDistance, info, source, false);

            int sealValue = (int) (gapValue * this.mScale);
            // gap shoud be greater than zero
            if (sealValue == 0)
                sealValue = 1;
        // To re-render the graph dates in domain axis
            ((DateAxis) this.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainAxis())
                    .setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.DAY,
                            sealValue, new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd")));

        }
    }

    // repaint
    invalidate();
```